# Add New Item When No Results in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UITableView that I am filtering with a UISearchDisplayController.  I would like to have my users search for an item. If they search for say, "Orange Juice", I would like to have a button either as the footer in the Search Table View that says "Add Orange Juice". In lieu of this, replacing the "No Results" text with "Add Orange Juice" would suffice as well.  Any suggestions on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement both UITableViewDelegate methods for having a footer view

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```